# Select from tables dynamically (table is variable)

Tags: sql

I have the case where I need to perform a query over a table that i do not know its name at design time.

For example, I have these tables:

```
Table_Items_1 
Table_Items_2 
Table_Items_3 
Table_Items_4 
Table_Items_5
```

I need to select depending on a number "x" which refers to the suffix of the table. (Number of tables is dynamic, I cannot do if-else).

This can be done using dynamic SQL. However, I need to have it more generic, since it will be referenced by several other functions/stored procedures.

I was thinking of a table-valued function, since I need to perform other queries over the above query (i.e.: inner joins, other select queries that depend on the result or fields etc.) but table-valued functions do not accept calling stored procedures nor dynamic SQL.

P.S.: I do not mind changing the method, TVF are not a must, yet, I need something generic that can be references from other stored procedures / functions.

Any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: for dynamic table name you have only one option it is `dynamic sql` and you cannot use dynamic sql inside anything other than a `stored procedure`.

Comment: Depending on the dbms used... Tag dbms product!

Comment: smells like bad database design to me.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - indeed, but sometimes you get tossed into maintaining existing systems with bad design, where refactoring it correctly is difficult (or in some cases, outright impossible).  Certain older enterprise level applications come to mind (particularly some CRM and ERP systems).

Comment: @user2366842 true :)

Answer (score 0):

Table name is not known in advance, its dynamic so you need dynamic sql.

Now depending on where and how the query is constructed you can either directly pass as command or use stored procedure.